# Cython updating object attributes

Tags: memory-management, cython, memoryview

I'm experimenting with a Cython object, where I would like to be able to repeatedly update its' attributes, according to some condition. The dummy code below is just swapping attributes arbitrarily to demonstrate the problem I'm encountering. I'm running this example in a Jupyter Notebook.

```
%load_ext Cython
```

```
%%cython -a

cdef class A_cy:  
    cdef int[:] a, b

    def __cinit__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

cpdef void swap_attributes_cy(int[:] x):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i
        A_cy container = A_cy(x, x)
        int _a

    for i in range(1000000): 
        _a = container.a

        container.a = container.b
        container.b = _a
```

When testing this against a version in pure python, i.e.

```
class A_py:  
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

def swap_attributes_py(x):
    container = A_py(x,x)

    for i in range(1000000):
        _a = container.a

        container.a = container.b
        container.b = _a
```

This cython version is slower (on my machine) than python (`~200ms` vs `~150ms`). **However** if I change the type of the attributes to `int`, the python version remains unchanged, but the Cython version takes `~110ns`! I'm struggling to understand why there is difference when attempting to swap a `memoryview` vs an `int`? Do I need to use `malloc`, `realloc` and `free` to swap memoryviews?

## Edit

If I use `cdef np.ndarray a, b` instead of `cdef int[:] a, b`, the cython version now takes `~6.7ms`. Can this still be improved however?

Comment: This isn't an operation that's optimized for memoryviews. What's quick for memoryviews is individual indexing. It's a lot like swapping objects, except with some additional type checking that shows it down. Why not just make the attributes `object`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DavidW. Yeah this seems to have a similar effect to using `cdef np.ndarray a, b`. Just to confirm, did you mean declare `cdef object a, b`?

Comment: Yes `cdef object a, b` (or just `cdef a, b` which is implicitly an object).

Comment: Understood, thanks for confirming. Out of interest, why is accessing and swapping attributes of type `int` (or any number type)  so much quicker than say an numpy array or even `object`? For this example `~110ns` vs `6.7ms`?

Comment: There's some reference counting in the `object`/`numpy.array` case. However, my guess is that the `int` case is sufficiently simple that it's optimized the whole loop out of existence because it's trivial to see what the result is at the end.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes a lot of sense. I was curious why changing the number of iterations wasn't changing the time elapsed for the `int` case. Thanks for clarifying!